# Accessibility Insights automated test differ from Axe

Tags: accessibility-insights, axe

Results of automated accessibility tests in the [Axe Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe-web-accessibility-tes/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd) differ from the results of [Accessibility Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/) automated tests. Since they both are using [axe-core](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core), what might be the reason?

I want to switch to the Accessibility Insights for thorough manual/assisted testing from Axe Beta, however, there are certain tests being shown in Axe, but missing in Accessibility Insights. The testing approach is the same for both tools, the page is fully loaded and scrolled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the automated checks of Accessibility Insights for Web we only show rules that are failures, we don’t show experimental or uncertain results (that might have false-positives) nor best practices rules. This helps users target accessibility failures and not second guess results.

Infrequently, we might also turn off a rule if there is a known false-positive.

We add a few experimental and uncertain/needs review results in the preview test Needs review. This test can be enabled by going to Settings > Feature flags in Accessibility Insights for Web.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I believe that the not-shown rules actually are failures too since it's directly connected to the WCAG, for example, "Links must have discernible text": https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.0/link-name - that's 2.4.4 and 4.1.2.

Perhaps I'm getting it wrong, but nevertheless, that's also an accessibility issue. It's not shown in the "Needs review" section.

Will there be an option to show even such violations in the future, please? I would love to have the possibility to include all kinds of rules, even the best practices.